# Настройка Selenium и Codeception в phpstorm

Tags: юнит-тесты, phpstorm, selenium, codeception

В общем пытаюсь настроить так получаю результат то что сервер запускается но тесты не запускаются, если запускать в отдельных терминалах, то есть запустить сервер отдельно, убрать из External tool то тесты запускаются. Как можно настроить так чтобы перед запуском тестов запускался сервер и закрывался когда тесты прошли.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте запуск и остановку селениума обычными баш-скриптами, выполняйте перед тестами и после тестов. Или, что еще проще, просто постоянно держите селениум включенным - сделайте его сервисом в ОС.

Comment: не знаком с bash  можете написать как это сделать